# jqPlot highlighter stay open after mouseout until next mouseover on other bar/point?

Tags: mouseover, jqplot, mouseout, highlighter

I need to display thumbnail images in jqplot highlighter tooltip, so to able click on them for displaying on fullscreen with lightbox, etc.

[image]

But wnen highlighter has opened by mouseover on the bar adn next i move the mouse in highlighter area he is dissapearing(mouseout from the bar). How to handle this to make highlighter still displaying until mouseover on other bar?

Answer (score 0):

I have returned to the project and found a solution in **jqplot.highlighter.js**, at row 409 have to comment:

```
            if (hl.fadeTooltip) {
                // hl._tooltipElem.fadeOut(hl.tooltipFadeSpeed);
            }
            else {
                // hl._tooltipElem.hide();
            }
```